# How does one use fields on a Table Type?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Given the following SQL User-Defined Table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerIdTableType AS TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

How does one use the `Id` field when the type is used as a parameter in a stored procedure such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindPencilsForPencilCases
    @pencilCaseIds dbo.IntegerIdTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Pencils
    INNER JOIN @pencilCaseIds ON @pencilCaseIds.Id = Pencils.PencilCaseId
END
```

I can get the above to run if I were to just run `SELECT * FROM @pencilCaseIds` but if I reference the `Id` field I instead get the following exception:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@pencilCaseIds".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an alias to the table valued parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindPencilsForPencilCases
    @pencilCaseIds dbo.IntegerIdTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Pencils
    INNER JOIN @pencilCaseIds AS tvp 
        ON tvp.Id = Pencils.PencilCaseId
END
```

Comment: This actually solved more issues in my real query than expected; I didn't realize that all complex type declarations needed to be aliased to access their underlying members.  I can now also reference fields on locally-declared tables using this aliasing technique.  I do question why SQL was designed this way though as it seems a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'm glad to help :-) though why it was designed this way I can't say.